# Alternative Gigabit Ethernet Connector - considerations for impedance, signal integrity, and EMC considerations?

Tags: connector, impedance, emc

I have a design that does not have enough vertical clearance for a standard RJ45 socket. I'm hoping to use a connector like this one from [Molex](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/5040500891_PCB_HEADERS.xml).

I will use Cat5e cable when building my cable with the alternative plug.

The question I have is what considerations need to be made when doing this from an impedance, signal integrity, and EMC perspective? (especially at gigabit speeds)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the datasheet about the connectors impedance. Perhaps you ought to consider some low-profile connectors that are specifically designed for Gigabit ethernet.

Comment: It will probably work, and with the right tuning stubs on the PCB to compensate for the connector it might even work well.

Comment: @uint128_t ... if only they existed.

Comment: @Jasen I'm curious how you would tune a fully differential signal with stubs

Comment: They do! [RJ point five connectors](http://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/input-output-connectors/rectangular-i-o/modular-jacks-plugs/rj-point-five-connectors.html). You can even buy cables from Office Depot! Granted, they aren't exactly cheap, but they do what you want.

Comment: @uint128_t I have seen those. The first problem is that the smallest socket connector they provide is a 2-up port, and since they are only half the size they are effectively no smaller for a 1-port application. The second issue is that I don't have enough vertical clearance and these are the same height just half the width.

Comment: Could you put them sideways? The 2 gang units. They're not really meant for that orientation, but maybe it'd work? Alternatively, what about Ethernet over USB3 or something? Granted, might be inappropriate for your application dependent on what you have inside.

Comment: Ah, yeah I like the USB 3.0 idea. It's 90 ohms but thats much closer than nothing.

Comment: @funkyeah, i don't know how they do it either, but I see weird traces when I dissasemble the cat5E socket inserts. used in structured wiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take: gigabit Ethernet is 125Mbaud, around 80MHz bandwidth, my guess of edge rate of a couple ns, edge travel distance of 1/3 of a meter. That should be a lot longer than the travel distance of the transition through the connector system. So the exact impedance does not matter that much.

Of course you want to avoid connectors with excessive capacitance and inductance. I think one way to check that is to measure the travel distance of the signal from the termination point at the PCB to the point where the cable unraveled. If that is shorter than the compliant RJ45 set up, then it is probably no worse than the RJ45 arrangement.

This also points out that when terminating the cable to the mating connector, it is necessary to control how much the cable get unraveled (un-twisted).

By the way, in the old days, PCB terminated RJ45 jacks almost always have the spring contacts on top (locking tap at the bottom). So the wire of a contact has to travel to the back of the jack and then down to the PCB. Now most jacks are flipped "upside down" so the traveling path becomes significantly shorter.

Comment: Thought you might like to know _why_ they were originally designed with the contacts on top: it was a dust issue. If the contacts were on the bottom, and nothing was plugged in for a while, dust could accumulate on the "floor" - where the contacts were. That dust could interfere with a cable when it was plugged in - or worse, be conductive and short something...